# Do I need to create a separate user to host a git repo with SSH connection

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to learn how to hot my own git server on Linux using SSH. I am reading [this tutorial](http://orange-coding.net/2012/08/24/creating-a-git-remote-repository-on-your-server/)

In this tutorial, it says to create a user for git. But it does not explain what I would want to create a user for git. Why would I want to do this? Can I not just keep the git repos under my main user?

This git repo is only for me, so could I not put it under my main user?

Comment: The main reason to add a `git` user is to export these repositories as public-access no-password-needed. You can then limit what the user `git` can see and export, and be less concerned about someone breaking in to the `git` account. If everything will be private and you will use only (direct, as-yourself) `ssh` access, you don't need to create a git user, nor set up repositories as exported through the `git://` protocol.

Comment: So what is the minimum required to access my repo remotely?

Comment: Just set things up so that you can log in with `ssh`.  Then `git clone ssh://name.of.host/~yourdir/path/to/repo.git`, for instance. Git will run `ssh` to access your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the tutorial uses ssh.

The idea is to let ssh handle the authentication through the addition of a user's public key to an Git hosting admin account `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
That way, multiple users can be authentication through that one account ssh session.

Hence a '`git`' user (with its `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file)

Even if you are the only user, it is a best practice to decouple Git access from Git administration, especially for ssh access.
That way, if interactive ssh shell session is achieved, you only have access to Git data, not your own personal data.

Comment: True enough, except that the page linked doesn't mention setting up an authorized_keys file (!) - though that might be a later step that I didn't see on my quick scan.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that I want to use SSH myself. Also I will only ever be hosting for 1 person....myself.

Comment: @ScottF My answer does mention ssh. Now this old tutorial isn't very accurate, as torek mentions. But still, the best practice remains: separate Git access from Git admin.

Comment: Yes, your answer does mention SSH, but I was just clarifying my intentions to use it, so you don't need so suppose alternate cases.

Comment: @ScottF As I mention in the answer, this is a best practice. You don't have to follow it. Using your own account is fine, as long as your register the public key your external account will use to access your repo on your own server.